# Unable to get updated circle position with Raphael.js

Tags: raphael

I am trying to drag around a circle with `raphael.js`, but it seems that `cx` and `cy` does not get updated for the circle in order to set the correct new positions of the circles.

The code can be seen and tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/MXFWW/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, applying a transformation to a Raphael object does not alter its positional attributes.

Check out the ellipsis syntax in the [transform method](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform). Because transformations are such a headache, I prefer in simple cases to directly alter the attributes. You just have to remember where you started in the dragStart function using the .data() method to store arbitrary data.

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 320, 320);
var innerC = paper.circle(320 / 2, 320 / 2, 20);
innerC.attr("stroke", "#000");
innerC.attr("fill", "#000");


var dragMove = function (dx, dy, x, y, e) {
    console.log(innerC.attr('cx'));
    this.attr("cx", this.data("ox") + dx);
    this.attr("cy", this.data("oy") + dy);
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity": 1
    }, 500);
},
dragStart = function (x, y) {
     this.data("ox", this.attr("cx"));
     this.data("oy", this.attr("cy"));
},

dragEnd = function () {
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity": 1
    }, 500);
};

innerC.drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragEnd);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXFWW/4/)

Comment: If i try to click down on the circle which not exactly in the middle, it tends to bounce the distance to the center point. Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: Ah, yes, you should do this: this.data("ox", this.attr("cx")) and likewise for y

Comment: Updated response and fiddle

Comment: If I have an array of circles in a set (representing a seating chart), and I make the set draggable, circles itself do not change cx/cy, only the set. What is the best way to store the geography of an entire set?

Comment: If you want to post a new question with some code, I'd be happy to answer.